# MongoDB + JS Date shifted -1 day

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, momentjs

I'm trying to add a new date inside my mongodb document using

```
db.collection('course').insertOne({
    date: new Date(item.date)
});
```

`item.date` is from

```
items.push({
    date: moment(new Date(day.label)).tz('Europe/Paris').format('YYYY/MM/DD'),
});
```

`day.label` is like `'14 November 2016'`

`item.date` is formated like `2016/11/14`

The document insert work but the dates are not properly formated, for example, for `2016/11/14` Mongo insert `"date" : ISODate("2016-11-13T23:00:00Z")`

Every inserted dates are shifted -1 day

Is the proper way to insert custom formated date in MongoDB ?
Should I change the momentJs date format ?

**EDIT:**

Dates are shifted because of different timezone.

Comment: Paris is in a different time zone than UTC, so that's where your difference comes from. Personally I'd store the date as a timestamp and convert it back into a date object when reading it out

Comment: Yea I just noticed that... I will try with timestamp instead. Thanks

Comment: You should always tell the parser the format you're trying to parse, otherwise it must guess.

Answer (score 1):

It's not shifted by a day, it's not actually shifted at all.

The time shown is shifted by an hour. If you notice, the time has become 23:00 on the previous day, rather than defaulting to midnight on the date you have specified.

More importantly, the Z suffix in the timestamp means that the timezone is UTC, and `2016-11-13T23:00:00` in UTC refers to the same moment in time as the timestamp `2016-11-14T00:00:00+01:00`. So the datetime is being created correctly, but just shown back to you in a different timezone that you're creating it in.

Answer (score 0):

if you want proper solution for all date UTC problem, store
date as standard ISO format

```
// India
moment().toISOString() // "2016-11-06T06:17:33.520Z"

// canada
moment().toISOString() // "2016-11-06T06:19:42.133Z"

now see the diffrence by convering date from database

// canada time zone
moment("2016-11-06T06:19:42.133Z").format() // "2016-11-05T23:19:42-07:00"

// india time zone 
moment("2016-11-06T06:19:42.133Z").format() //"2016-11-06T11:49:42+05:30"
```

as above see the diffrence of local UTC, so don't have to convert date from any
timezone to other timezone